# Regexp group matching one more character then group should?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm guessing that I'm confused about how groups work in regexp.
My regexp replaces more characters then it should.
Here is my string:

```
...test - Copy\asd.test2\asd.keke
```

And here is my pattern:

```
.?(asd\.)
```

It matches "\asd." but I want it to match just "asd."

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: If you can show us how you're getting the match... It may be that you're retrieving the whole match rather than just the matched group.

Comment: Is it anything to do with the \. you have? E.g. Try .?(asd) - This is a total guess though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve using `.?` if you don't want to match it?

To check for characters outside of your match, you can use lookaround assertion. E.g. checking for a backslash before the match, you'd use

```
(?<=\\)asd\.
```

Comment: My regexp knowledge is still at a low level, so I've misunderstood the use of `.?`. Thank you!